# trap os.Exit in golang

Tags: go

I can run some cleanup on interruption (when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>).

```
$ go build 
$ ./exit
^Creceived interrupt signal
```

Is it possible to trap the same way `os.Exit` call and run some code before program exits? The code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    handleInterrupt(2)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    os.Exit(1) // how to trap it?
}
func handleInterrupt(intrptChSize int) {
    s := make(chan os.Signal, intrptChSize)
    signal.Notify(s,
        syscall.SIGABRT,
        syscall.SIGALRM,
        syscall.SIGBUS,
        syscall.SIGCHLD,
        syscall.SIGCONT,
        syscall.SIGEMT,
        syscall.SIGFPE,
        syscall.SIGHUP,
        syscall.SIGILL,
        syscall.SIGINFO,
        syscall.SIGINT,
        syscall.SIGIO,
        syscall.SIGIOT,
        syscall.SIGKILL,
        syscall.SIGPIPE,
        syscall.SIGPROF,
        syscall.SIGQUIT,
        syscall.SIGSEGV,
        syscall.SIGSTOP,
        syscall.SIGSYS,
        syscall.SIGTERM,
        syscall.SIGTRAP,
        syscall.SIGTSTP,
        syscall.SIGTTIN,
        syscall.SIGTTOU,
        syscall.SIGURG,
        syscall.SIGUSR1,
        syscall.SIGUSR2,
        syscall.SIGVTALRM,
        syscall.SIGWINCH,
        syscall.SIGXCPU,
        syscall.SIGXFSZ)
    go func() {
        for sig := range s {
            fmt.Printf("received %s signal\n", sig)
            //cleanup()
        }
    }()
}
```

I know I can just run `cleanup` before each `os.Exit()` code manually in this example:

```
cleanup()
os.Exit(1)
```

But in my real project I am importing code which I cannot edit. This code contains `os.Exit` calls and I would like to do some cleanup before the program exits without editing imported code.

Comment: You should really only handle signals that make sense. You probably don't wan't to "cleanup" from non terminating signals like `SIGWINCH`, or on every `SIGALRM/SIGCTALRM`, `SIGXCPU`, etc. You also have signals in there that can't be handled at all.

Comment: Instead of the nuclear option of `os.Exit(x)` try a variant of: https://play.golang.org/p/kHIfKoXuKt

Comment: @MartinGallagher I cannot remove os.Exit(x) from imported code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. from TFM:

> The program terminates immediately; deferred functions are not run.